# Mac Pro trashcan as file server for 60+ users

Tags: network, mac-pro, dropbox, afp

I'm wondering if anyone out there has had any experience using a Mac Pro trashcan as a file server for a medium business.  My concern is that it won't be able to handle the network traffic for 60+ connected users (AFP).

The reason I am not wanting to use a NAS or something like that is that I need to have dropbox on the server syncing the shared volume.

Does anyone have any experience with a scenario like this?

Comment: You may be interested to learn [Synology NAS supports Dropbox](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/6.1/cloud_file_syncing).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should reconsider a NAS because using a Mac Pro is complete overkill when a NAS will do exactly what you want including sync to public cloud services like DropBox, OneDrive, Box.net, etc.

I am a fan of [Synology](https://www.synology.com/en-us/) products because whether you are using their entry level single disk NAS devices or their enterprise grade rack mount solutions, the software and features are the same.   Specifically, to your question, it includes [Cloud Sync](https://www.synology.com/en-us/dsm/6.1/cloud_file_syncing) which will sync up with DropBox.

Also, consider moving from AFP to SMB.  AFP has been deprecated in Yosemite in favor of SMB2.  AFP is also not compatible with the new APFS.
However, most NAS devices will still provide AFP for backward compatibility.

Finally, I suggest you utilize their "[NAS calculator](https://www.synology.com/en-us/support/nas_selector)" because sizing a file sharing solution is more than just how many people it needs to serve, but the type of files, how much space, your iops requirement etc.

Comment: This is really helpful.  Thank you.  I'm going to look into this stuff.

Comment: How does this work with Spotlight?  If I wanted to use something like [alfred](https://www.alfredapp.com) how would that work?

Comment: I am not familiar with alfred so I can't talk to that point,  but you can include Spotlight indexes using `mdutil`  Type `man mdutil` in Terminal for more info.

Comment: Spotlight will work if you 1)attach the NAS folder/drive to your Mac, and 2) tell Spotlight to scan it

Comment: I ended up purchasing a Synology NAS and it has been working great so far.  The Dropbox (Cloud Sync) functionality is really pretty great.  It's been a couple of months, and it's proven to be a reliable solution.

Comment: Glad you found something that works well for you!  One last thing...invest in a UPS (I use APC) and hook it up to the Synology.  It will automatically do a clean shutdown if power goes. It proved its value to me during Hurricane Irma when I couldn't log in to do it manually due to the Internet being down.  When power was restored, everything came back clean.